# Navigation with elm-reactor

Tags: routes, navigation, elm, elm-reactor

I have an elm 0.18 app that uses the Navigation module.  I navigate within it using links that look like `[ a [ href "/#/page" ] [ text "Page" ]`, and do redirects with `Navigation.newUrl myNewUrl`.

When I fire up elm-reactor, though, everything is coming from the location `http://localhost:8000/src/main.elm/`, and clicking the link above takes me to `http://localhost:8000/#/page`.  This works fine with my webpack code, but it sends me back to the main page for elm-reactor.

What is the correct way to navigate different pages within an elm app and continue using elm-reactor?

Answer (score 0):

Your links go back to the root of the site because the `href` value starts with a slash. If you just want to change the hash value, start instead with the hash character:

```elm
[ a [ href "#/page" ] [ text "Page" ]
```

Elm Reactor is really only useful as a lightweight debugging tool. If you are trying to link to different pages and modules within your project, then Elm Reactor is probably not a good fit. You may be better served by using your webpack live-reload functionality rather than trying to alter your code to suit a debugging environment.